# Send data to the old activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am starting my old Activity by using Flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` but I cann't send String to this Activity by using `putExtra`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(INTENT_ActivityA);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("DATA", "OK");
startActivity(intent);
```

in the `onResume` `getIntent().getStringExtra("DATA")==null`

How to send data to the running Activity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you override onNewIntent i think you should be having your data in it. Try following

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    intent.getStringExtra("DATA");
}
```

Hope it helps!